# PDO gives error "could not find driver"

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
<?
$dsn = 'mysqli:dbname=websiteusers;host=localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '123';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

It gives error could not find driver.
What can i do?

Comment: You have a typo: `mysqli:` should be `mysql:`.

Comment: Is this question still open or were you able to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and the php docs for PDO are saying is that PDO doesn't support mysqli since there is an own class/adapter handling mysqli connections.

[Supported PDO Drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php)

[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: But i took this code from the same website and i didnt change anything only hostname and username.Plus i changed mysqli to mysql but its stil same

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the PDO driver for mysql is not enabled on your server. Check your php.ini file for the following line:

;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Answer (score 0):

The driver is called mysql, not mysqli.

Comment: Then you dont have `PDO_MYSQL` driver installed/enabled, even if you have `PDO` itself